# CORMEN explanation of Insertion Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I can't understand this particular use of the sigma(summation) notation in the explanation of the Insertion sort of the book *Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS*:

[image: See this Image]

Let tj denote the number of times the while loop test in line 5 is executed for that value of j.

Can someone explain the use of sigma(summation) in Line 5,6,7?
I am aware of the summation formulas and uses.

Comment: how will the expression t2+t3+t4...+tn  be handled???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note - the sigma expressions should be j instead of t[j]. I'm not sure why the book used t[j] since it's using expressions of n for the other lines.

The sigma's are expressing the number of times that the corresponding line will be executed (worst case). For Sigma(j=2 to n) on line 5, that's a total count of 2+3+4+...+n = (n+2)(n-1)/2 = 1/2 n^2 + 1/2 n - 1. Note that for line 5, for j = 2, it's counting line 5 twice, once for i = 1 (the first compare of i > 0) and once for i = 0 (the second compare of i > 0).

Lines 6 and 7 depend A[i]> key, and worst case (A[i] always > key), loop one less than line 5, which explains the (tj - 1) factor => (2-1)+(3-1) + ... = 1+2+3+...+n-1 = (n)(n-1)/2.

Comment: tj denotes the no of times while statement runs for each value of j i.e (for worst case ) tj = j for j=2,3,4...n.

Comment: @rigene - Why use tj for lines 4, 5, 6, and not use tn or nt for line 1 or t(n-1) or (n-1)t for the other lines? Seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: because line 4,5,6 depends on the worst case, average case and best case inputs and the line other than 4,5,6 do not depend on input.

Answer (score 2):

I think I finally can clearly understand.

The Sigma is expressing that for each j, the while loop may run up to t times. So, when j is equal to 2, the while loop will run t times, when j is equal to 3, the while loop will run t times, but since we don't know if this t, when j=3, is equal to the previous t, when j = 2, we add a subscript to indicate that there are different t's.

The sum runs from 2 to n, and this already represent the for loop that is running in the outer layer.

So, in summary, the limits are from 2 to n, and each time we are in the for loop and we get to the while loop, this while loop will run t times.

Comment: Your explanation matches with that of the book's author(s). Their explanation is given in the paragraph preceding the pseudocode OP used. They mentioned "*we let tj denote the number of times the while loop test in line 5 is executed for that value of j*". However, I could understand that seemingly straighforwad sentence only after reading your answer. So +1.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained like:

- [Outer loop] Line five will iterate `2 to n` times (Let it is `t` times)

  - [Inside loop] Line six and seven will iterate same times from `2 to (t-1) times.